# Parsing JSON freezes tableView SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, performance, uitableview, parsing

My current problem is that when the function `updateLabels` is called my tableView freezes. 
My goal is to update radio stations song names and titles every 15 seconds. I have a dict array that holds the info and the function that populates that dict array every 15s. Each station has a separate `JSON` link file that I put into my `getData` function parameters. What can I do to make it better and stop tableView to freeze?

**main array**

```
var songNames = [
                (songArtist: "", songName: ""),
                (songArtist: "", songName: ""),
                .....
            ]
```

**update songs title and names**

```
func updateLabels() {
    songNames.removeAll()   
    songNames.append((songArtist: getData("rd").artistName, songName: " - \(getData("record").songName)"))
    songNames.append((songArtist: getData("mix").artistName, songName: " - \(getData("mix").songName)"))
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**get data from JSON link**

```
func getData(urlPart: String) ->(artistName: String, songName: String) {
    let mainURl = "http://...json"
    let url = NSURL(string: mainURl)
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:  nil)
    let songArtistName = readableJSON["ARTIST"]
    let songName = readableJSON["NAME"]                
    return (songArtistName.description, songName.description)
}
```

**in my `viewDidLoad`**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateLabels()
    //**Timer to call the function every 15 sec**
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateLabels), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Of course it freezes if you're downloading data on main thread. Look up how to do it asynchronously.

Comment: Do I need to use Alamofire?

Comment: It's handy, because it's the standard way to do it, but in your case it doesn't seem like it. Just look at how dispatch_async functions work and wrap it around your download code. Don't forget to jump up to the main queue when you need to update the UI!

Comment: Use NSURLSession. An example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264172/how-can-i-get-the-data-from-nsurlsession-sharedsession-datataskwithrequest

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main problem is because you are getting `JSON` data on the main thread, that is why UI freezes. Instead of doing it on the main thread you should dispatch this task `async` on background thread.

At the end of `async` background task, iOS SDK will switch program flow to the main thread, where you must update your UI components with fetched `JSON` data.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

   // Get JSON data here

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Update UI here
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using threading / Grand Central Dispatch If you don't know it. Just do like..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in

//call your function here..

})
```

If it's not resolving just comment below.. I will help..

Comment: I throw my NSTimer inside dispatch_async and the app stays frozen

Comment: No need for using NSTimer.. Instead of NSTimer Try using this     'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {() -> Void in
            // time-consuming task'   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
 })

Comment: will it run only once though?

Comment: yes It will.. First main queue will be executed and then another wil in background

Comment: but I need it to execute every 15 sec

Comment: No problem you can deal with delay... find the time thread on internet and execute.. You have to apply thread concept in your own way.. we can guide you but you are the only who can apply.. please make some research on thread..