# How to dynamically load urls (in the form if images) in collection view in swift ios?

Tags: ios

I have this array of names as below

`["Acting Chief Justice Gita Mittal", "Justice S. Ravindra Bhat", "Justice Sanjiv Khanna", "Justice G. S. Sistani", "Justice Dr. S. Muralidhar", "Justice Hima Kohli", "Justice Vipin Sanghi", "Justice Siddharth Mridul", "Justice Manmohan"]`

and  Array of  URLs as below

```
["writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_7ZV0X5SB.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_31PR55RK.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_TALSLWYH.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_DDW7F8I4.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_8MP3TXZ2.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_3R72I03Q.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_ZPL72GGF.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_RHXYPY1N.JPG", "writereaddata%5Cupload%5CJudges/JImage_BR82DUAU.JPG"]
```

I want to display these in collection view in swift on runtime on image and label . How to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by runtime?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage?noredirect=1#comment79363649_46199203

Answer (score 1):

There is a great swift library for downloading and caching images called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Check the docs it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library to load image from `URL` in TableView and CollectionView.

You like this in `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` cell.

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "yourImageURL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```