# Assigning Image into UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I cannot find the solution for the issue. 
I have the following code

```
let imgData = self.getImgData(id: (entry["id"] as? Int)!)
let imgToShow = UIImage(data: imgData as Data)
```

where imgToShow is this what I expected. 
I mean, when debugging it's giving me the preview of this what I want. So I am sure that it's correct and not nil.

```
public func getImgData(id: Int) -> NSData{
    let url = *
    let imgUrl = URL(string: url)!
    let imgData = NSData(contentsOf: imgUrl)!

    return imgData

}
```

I would like to assign this `imgToShow` to `cell.img.image = imgToShow`
but it's giving me an error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Can you please give me some advice where should I look the solution?
Thank you in advance

Comment: post the code of `self.getImgData(id: (entry["id"] as? Int)!)`

Comment: Thanks, updated. But I can guess that the function works fine as I can see the preview of the image when debugging.

Comment: If your claim that " `imgToShow` is not nil " is correct , then I think problem is in this part : `cell.img` , so please check that your cell is made properly and also check `img` property is correctly made

Comment: So, I have tried to use @SalmanGhumsani solution, calling 
`getImage(url) { (data) in
            cell.img.image = data
            
        }`
The image has been downloaded, I can see it while debugging, but in line where assigning it to UIImageView getting the same. 
So could be the problem with `img`, which just looks like this:
`class AuthorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.imgId.isHidden = true
    }
    }  
}`
But where should I looking for

Comment: It's working great! Thanks. 
So the problem was with UIImageView item, as there was very simple, stupid mistake. During refactoring I have changed the name of Outlet, but the old one name has been referenced. Just reconnected Outlet and this is what I want. I have wasted 2 days on it.. It was so simple. Anyway, thank you again for the lesson, that always should check references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to reconnect the outlet!**

Also, for getting download the image smoothly try it [Downloading UIImage via AlamofireImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage/46199246#46199246)