# Issue with displaying tableview cell image with AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am downloading and showing thumbnails from server with `AlamofireImage` , the downloading works fine but when I scroll tableivew cell image changes all the time , I have searched and did not find any solution for example `prepareForReuse` in custom cell calls. Here is my code :

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TrendingCell

        let trendingIndex = trendingArray[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]

        if let media = trendingIndex["thumbnails"] as? [String:Any] {
            if let thumbnail = media["medium"] as? [String:Any] {
                thumbnailURL = String(describing:thumbnail["url"]!)
            }
        }



        Alamofire.request(thumbnailURL).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.thumbnail.image = image
             }

        }

        return cell
    }
```

How to avoid image changing when user scrolls tableview ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage/46199246#46199246

Comment: I would suggest using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library for images

Comment: You have to write it with cell imageView

Comment: Your cells are most likely being reused. Try doing `cell.thumbnail.image = nil` after you initialise you `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Thank you it worked

Comment: Ohh great happy to help :)

Comment: what is the fix post it as a  answer so other will know ?

Comment: @Vinodh check the answer

Answer (score 1):

As Salman Ghumsani  mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage/46199246#46199246) :

we can use `AlamofireImage` extension to set a default thumbnail like this :

```
  //Download and set thumbnail
        if let imageURL = URL(string: thumbnailURL), let placeholder = UIImage(named: "Default") {
            cell.thumbnail.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL, placeholderImage: placeholder) //set image automatically when download compelete.
        }
```

Now when you scroll table view images did not change.