# UIImageView, Load UIImage from remote URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiimageview, uiimage

This problems it's driving me crazy...
I have this string `url`:
"**verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg**" 
and I have to load this image in my `imageView`.

this is my code :

```
do {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg")
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
```

This throw the exception :

> No such file or directory.

But if I search this `url` with a browser I can see the image correctly!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199203/downloading-uiimage-via-alamofireimage/46199246#46199246

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using wrong method to create URL. Try `URLWithString` instead of `fileURLWithPath`. `fileURLWithPath` is used to get image from local file path not from internet url.

or

```
do {
    let url = URL(string: "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg")
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: You should not use `Data(contentsOf: url)` with remote URLs as stated by the documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init

This will block the current thread.

You should use `URLSession.dataTask()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The method `fileURLWithPath` opens file from file system. The file address is prepended with `file://`. You can print the url string.

From Apple documentation about `+ (NSURL *)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path;`

> The path that the NSURL object will represent. path should be a valid
>   system path, and must not be an empty path. If path begins with a
>   tilde, it must first be expanded with stringByExpandingTildeInPath. If
>   path is a relative path, it is treated as being relative to the
>   current working directory.

Here is one of a few possible solutions:

```
let imageName = "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg"

func loadImage(with address: String) {

    // Perform on background thread
    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        // Create url from string address
        guard let url = URL(string: address) else {
            return
        }

        // Create data from url (You can handle exeption with try-catch)
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            return
        }

        // Create image from data
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
            return
        }

        // Perform on UI thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            /* Do some stuff with your imageView */
        }
    }
}

loadImage(with: imageName)
```

It's best practice if you just send a completion handler to perform on main thread to `loadImage(with:)`.

Comment: i suppose that simply overt url in data is a bad practice, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here the url is not of the local system but of the server.

```
  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg")
```

**Here the url created is of file which is locally on the device.**
**Create url like this:-**

```
  url = URL(string: "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to loading an image into imageview

```
 func imageDownloading() {

    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let url = URL(string: "http://verona-api.municipiumstaging.it/system/images/image/image/22/app_1920_1280_4.jpg")!

        do {

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

            }

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```