# Wait until getting response from PHP in swift

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Tavolo n° " + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "number")!
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor =  UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.69, blue: 0.31 , alpha: 1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white;
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    name.delegate = self

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.116/myorder/data/fetch_name.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "number=\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "number"))";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        var _: NSError?

        do{

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray

            if let parseJSON: NSArray = json {

                for index in 0...parseJSON.count-1 {
                    if (parseJSON[index] is NSNull){
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Attenzione\n", message: "Nessun nominativo per questo tavolo", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
                    }else{
                        let nomi = parseJSON[index] as! [String:Any]
                        ViewController.listNames.append(nomi["name"] as! String)
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume();
    print(ViewController.listNames)
    selectedName = ViewController.listNames[0]

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NamesVC.keyboardWillShow(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NamesVC.keyboardWillHide(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Sometimes the response returns before printing the first element of ViewController.listNames, but sometimes not so it prints nothing.
How can I wait until the response returns? I have tried other answers on stackOverflow, but I can't do it

Comment: Rather than waiting, move the code that uses `listNames` into the completion handler so you're sure you have the data before referencing it.

Comment: You don't wait. You never do. You use a callback instead. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31264556/2227743

Comment: Completely unrelated but the line `var _: NSError?` is hilarious (and useless) :-)

Comment: I tried using a completion handler like the one you have posted @Moritz but it didn't work. Now I'll try with the answer in your link

Comment: @vadian I know that in my code there are some errors because I'm quite new in programming in Swift

Comment: I tried your answer @Moritz but it prints that line in viewDidLoad before printing the json like in the link

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you `resume` the task, it goes off and gets data over the internet, which might take some time. Because of that, `resume` finishes immediately instead of waiting until the network connection finishes. Your `print` is on the next line. Sometimes the network connection will be fast and it will finish before you reach the `print`. Other times it won't be so fast and the `print` happens first. It's a classic example of a race condition-- two things run separately from each other, and it's unpredictable which one will finish first.

All of this is why the task has a completion block-- which is your closure that begins with `if error != nil{`. Code inside that closure won't happen until the task finishes.

You should put your `print` statement inside that closure, so that you can be sure that the network connection has finished before it happens.

Comment: I know that is a "race condition" as you said. The print line is only an example. In my case with the names that return from PHP, I want to show a pickerView (I haven't post it in my question). Sometimes the pickerView loads with the names and sometimes not. I want that it loads always with the names that are returning, also if the connection is low and it takes more time

Comment: The same thing I said about the print statement applies-- if the code depends on the results of the call, it needs to be inside that closure. Or else, it needs to be triggered by a call from the closer (maybe a notification that the network call is completed, that causes the UI to reload).

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying but I can't do it. I display the pickerView with principal methods: numberOfRowsInComponent, titleForRow...

Comment: You probably need to call `reloadAllComponents()` from the closure, to tell the picker to load the new data.

Comment: I have done this and it works, but I see that the names appear one second later and I think it is not so good in an app (there is a kind of delay)

Comment: Are you sure that you're doing that on the main queue? UI updates from other queues are usually delayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157409/discussion-between-marco-and-tom-harrington).

Comment: Let's not. You're now asking about things that are completely unrelated to your original question. You should ask a new question for your current needs.

Comment: Ok, but with lot of tests I noticed that your method doesn't wait always the response