# SwiftyJSON deep copy

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm doing a ServerTransport class and I'm running into a bit of a problem ... 
 Long story short, I want a ServerTransport object to be able to get and/or post data at  `self.link`. 
The class member `self.dataOut` is supposed to hold whatever is coming from the server.
The method `receive()` should create the request and put everything into dataOut.

I'm using SwiftyJSON and I learned about the `merged(with:)` method. 
I had hoped to create a temporary constant called json, and deep copy it into self.dataOut. Just to be extra sure, I merged json with itself.
No such luck. Whenever the json constant goes out of scope, the self.dataOut member becomes JSON() once again.

Am I doing something wrong? Is what I intend to do even possible?
Below is my code.

---

Thanks in advance.

```
class ServerTransport {
var dataIn: Data?
var dataOut : JSON
var link: String
var responseType : String

init(_ link : String, _ responseType : String = "application/json", _ dataIn : Data? = nil) {
    self.dataIn = dataIn
    self.link = link
    self.responseType = responseType
    self.dataOut = JSON()
}

func receive() {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.link)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error : \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
          return
        }

        if let mimeType = response.mimeType, mimeType == self.responseType, let data = data{
            guard let json = try? JSON(data : data) else {
                return
            }
            do {
               self.dataOut = try json.merged(with: json)
            }catch {
                print("exception")
                // nothing let's just hope that we won't ever reach this point
            }
        }
        print(self.dataOut) // Correct data from server
    }
    task.resume()
    print(self.dataOut) // Empty JSON ... Is it because the json variable is out of scope ?
    // Wasn't merge supposed to give a deep copy of json?
}
```

Comment: `json.merged(with: json)` Do you want to merge 2 identical `JSON` and set to `self.dataOut`?

Comment: It should be `self.dataOut = self.dataOut.merged(with: json)` if I'm understanding your question right.

Comment: I'm merging the same json twice to be extra sure that I WILL have the correct json in `self.dataOut`. As far as I'm concerned, `self.dataOut.merged(with:json)` produces exactly the very same result. What I don't understand is why its value changes before and after the `task.resume()` ...
Sometimes, an output before the `task.resume()` appears (chronologically) after the an output after  ...

Comment: You got to print `self.dataOut` inside the block. It is async task.

Comment: You might do yourself a favour by dropping `SwiftyJSON` and go with the [`Codable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable), it is great at turning your random piece of JSON (tm) into some _real_ Swift object.

Comment: As can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264172/how-can-i-get-the-data-from-nsurlsession-sharedsession-datataskwithrequest) `task.resume()` just _starts_ the task. It _does not_ wait for completion. You will have to provide some other mechanism to get to know when your task is finished. @Ryan's comment is key to this.

Comment: @Patru It’s not a great place to discuss about benefit of using SwiftyJSON but the codable still has limitation which can be easily implemented with SwiftyJSON.

Comment: @Ryan: You see me blush and you are probably right. I never used `SwiftyJSON` to any extent, but I absolutely admire what `Codable` can do. So I probably do not know what I am talking here. `merge`ing JSON returned from a WebService to an object property looks like a strange idea though.