# Getting data out of a swift closure

Tags: swift

I am struggling to understand Swift closures, particularly how to get data out of them. The following code makes a http get request and retrieves data from a URL. Which all works fine. I can print out this data within the closure but cannot work out how store into an external variable or return the data. The *routes* variable is nil when the code completes. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and/or how to get the data out of the closure.

```
var routes: [String]?

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    } //end let
    do {
    if let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        if let response = jsonDict.value(forKey: "response") as? NSArray {
            for i in 0..<response.count {
                let route = response.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
                print(route.value(forKey: "route_id")!)
                routes?.append(route.value(forKey: "route_id")! as! String)

            }
        self.routes = routes
        print(self.routes)
        }
    }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

OUTPUT:

```
11201-20180605110613_v67.1

11202-20180524131340_v66.89

11201-20180524131340_v66.89

11202-20180605110613_v67.1

nil
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31264172/2227743 and many similar Q&As. Use a callback (in the given example, used for a String, so replace that with an array of strings in your case).

Comment: and don't use NS classes (NSDictionary, NSArray etc) in Swift unless forced to

Comment: Great thanks for that